# overriding RIA DomianService code generation

Tags: ria, t4, domain-service-class

I need to insert a common set of code in Get method of all the entities generated by the RIA Domain Service wizard. Is it possible to override Domain Service wizard's code generation so I can insert that code automatically?

Thanks,
Ankur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely modify and edit (or even write your own) T4 templates that are responsible for the code generation.. something along the lines of these two links:

[T4 Code Generator for WCF RIA Services](http://varunpuranik.wordpress.com/2010/11/05/t4-code-gen/)

[Using T4 to change the way RIA services work](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/willemm/archive/2011/02/08/using-t4-to-change-the-way-ria-services-work.aspx)

Furthermore, you can check the T4 template for RIA services (server side) from the [WCF RIA Services Contrib project on CodePlex](http://riaservicescontrib.codeplex.com/) that allows you to modify your GET methods as follows:

```
public IQueryable<<#= Entity.Name #>> Get<#= Entity.Name #>()
{
     //Inject Custom code here
     return this.ObjectContext.<#= Entity.Mapping.StoreEntitySet #>;
}
```

Comment: The "blogs.infosupport" link is giving a 403 Forbidden error.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a [great blog-post](http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET36) written by Stefan Cruysberghs covering this topic.

He is using the [RIAServices.T4 nuget-package](http://nuget.org/packages/RIAServices.T4/) to modify the code that is being generated on the client side. The referenced article covers this in great detail, but the essence is as follows:

- Add the nuget-package to the project containg the services
- Implement your own code generator using a pre-defined base class

  ```csharp
  public class MyDomainContextGenerator : CSharpDomainContextGenerator
  {
      protected override void GenerateClassDeclaration()
      {
          // Add something before the class generation here...
          base.GenerateClassDeclaration();
      }
  }
  ```
- Advise RIAServices to use that generator by means of an attributed class:

  ```csharp
  [DomainServiceClientCodeGenerator("MyCodeGenerator", "C#")]
  public class MyCodeGenerator : CSharpClientCodeGenerator
  {
      protected override DomainContextGenerator DomainContextGenerator
      {
          get { return new MyDomainContextGenerator(); }
      }
  }
  ```